# symfony2 fosuserbundle login from browser?

Tags: symfony

I have used symfony up until 1.4 and I'm now picking it up from 2.8. Things seemed to be a lot easier back then. All I want is to create a user from the browser. I seem to have succesfully installed symfony as I get a welcome message in my browser. I seem also succesfully have installed fosuserbundle, as I got a database success message on the command line. Now I want to register a user, but I get 404's when I go to http://localhost/app.php/register or to http://localhost/register. The "register"-route is mentioned at http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Of course, this is working: http://localhost/app.php/

The tutorials seem to assume you know a lot about symfony, but this should be something all new users want to use?

Comment: hmmm, app_dev.php/register does work.

Comment: But `app.php` is the front-end file used to access the application deployed in production and not during the development in locale. Read all the related docs more carefully.

Comment: Yeah... "all the related docs"...

Comment: If `app_dev.php/register` works, clear the cache `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` and then try your route again.

Answer (score 0):

in Symfony 2:

- app.php runs the production environment
- app_dev.php runs the development environment

If you don't like this approach you have 2 solutions:

- Rename app_dev.php to index.php in development and point your .htaccess to it

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
  ```
- Create an index.php file and rely on environment variables to determine your application environment, something like this:

  ```
  defined('SYMFONY_ENV') || define('SYMFONY_ENV', (getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ? getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') : 'prod'));

  switch (SYMFONY_ENV) {
  case 'prod':
      require __DIR__ . '/app.php';
      break;

  case 'dev':
  case 'staging':
  case 'test':
      require __DIR__ . '/app_dev.php';
      break;

  default:
      header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
      exit('Improper SYMFONY_ENV set. See ' . basename(__FILE__) . ' for more information.');
  ```

  }

you can set your environment variable in the .htaccess like this

```
    SetEnv SYMFONY_ENV development
```